# Rest API not able to get items from list which has crossed the threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am querying list using REST.

API: `siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/items?$top=5000&$filter=((BBEmail eq '"+_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName+"')or(OpexCatalystEmail eq '"+_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName+"')or(PEGLeadEmail eq '"+_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName+"'))&$orderby=Modified desc";`

The fields below are indexed.

- BBEmail
- PEGLeadEmail
- OpexCatalystEmail
- Modified

Still getting the threshold error when hitting the api.

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024860,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The
>   attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the
>   administrator.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-2147024860,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the
>   administrator."}}},"status":500,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0):

the `$top=5000` only seems to work when there is no filter or `orderby`. You'll have to filter on the front end after the results are returned. I haven't found any solution around this. If I do I'll come back and update my answer. I have seen some suggest that the columns that you `filter` on and `orderby` need to be indexed. Mine are indexed and I still get the `threshold` error.

update:
even though this is speaking to 2010 this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54957/how-to-make-rest-or-soap-queries-on-a-large-list-in-sp2010) seems to point what has been tested as true. The filter results have to be under 5k otherwise you'll hit the threshold limit.